# How to generate external url in WordPress

Tags: urls

I want to link a external url as follows:

```
$url='www.example.com';
$output ='<div class="button"><a href="'.$url.'"> View Profile</a></div>';
```

I run this wordpress web app at my localhost and base url is localhost/wordpress.
When I echo `$output` it produce a link for view profile: `localhost/wordpress/www.example.com`. But it should be `www.facebook.com`

What change shall i make?

Comment: Use `http://` or `https://` before your URL.

Answer (score 2):

@Sam is close, but I think you need to do this:

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com';
```

Without the protocol in front, you get the wrong result. Change to

```
$url = 'https://www.example.com';
```

if you need an SSL link.

Answer (score 0):

You have a / thats not needed in the href this will add the link to the end of your current url hence localhost/wordpress/www.example.com

```
    $url='www.example.com';
    $output ='<div class="button"><a href="'.$url.'"> View Profile</a></div>';
    echo $output;
```